# Kafka Connection Problem with Docker Compose

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I have below docker compose yml,

```
version: '3.5'
services:

  zookeeper:
    container_name: kafka-zookeeper
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    networks:
      - my-network

  kafka:
    container_name: kafka-server
    image: wurstmeister/kafka:2.12-2.5.0
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    links:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    networks:
      - my-network
networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

I referred the below reference,

https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker/wiki/Connectivity

My spring boot application.yml file as below,

```
kafka:
  bootstrap:
    url: 127.0.0.1:9092
```

The error is,

```
[taKafkaProducer] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=SensorDataKafkaProducer] Connection to node -1 (/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

I can connect Kafka via client tool and see listener details `127.0.0.1:9092`

```
bd919e5a4df2        wurstmeister/kafka:2.12-2.5.0       "start-kafka.sh"         About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:9092->9092/tcp                                      kafka-server

9b94b7dac237        wurstmeister/zookeeper:3.4.6        "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   22/tcp, 2888/tcp, 3888/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2181->2181/tcp          kafka-zookeeper
```

any issue with config?

Comment: Could you please clarufy whether you are running the spring-boot application from outside the docker environment ? For me, it works to access by dns name, i.e. `url: kafka-server:9092` and also `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-server:9092`

Comment: I am running inside the container.

Comment: I believe you should be able to access by dns name, if link the app to service,

Comment: I will try now, and keep posted. Thanks Mikalai.

Comment: Awesome, it's working now. I wanted to verify them in Kafka client tool, i can't connect with the```kafka-server:9092``` or ```127.0.0.1:9092```. Do i need any specific config in yml file?

Comment: Try adding KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: whatever your machine's IP address is to your docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a user-defined bridge network, containers can resolve each other by name or alias. Thus, in your case the application.yml should point at the kafka container name:

```yaml
kafka:
  bootstrap:
    url: kafka-server:9092
```

Also, for it works to configure the kafka advertised listener by container name as well:

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka-server:9092
```